Parent class without parent's parent class
Can I inherit the parent class, but without the parent's parent class?
Example:
class A:
    var: int = 0

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)

class B(A):
    ...

class C(B):
    ...

I want class B to inherit the var variable, and class C should not
Also, __init_subclass__ should not work for class C, that is, I should only get the label "B" on the output (From cls.__name__)
I can't redefine __init_subclass__ in class B, as it would be inconvenient in my case. Class A is the basic model for sets of similar classes B.
Is it possible to solve this somehow without making any changes to class B?
Updated:
Why do I need this?
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class StructModuleBase:
    TableName: str = field(init = False, repr = False)
    ...
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, as_table = None, **kwargs) -> None:
        cls.TableName = cls.__name__.replace('Struct', '', 1)
        ...

@dataclass
class StructSettings(StructModuleBase):
    key_setting: str
    value_setting: str
    ...

@dataclass
class DataclassModuleBase:
    _database: str = field(repr = False)
    ...


@dataclass
class Setting(StructSettings, DataclassModuleBase):
    ...

I need to inherit key_setting and value_setting from the StructSettings class in the Setting class, but I don't need __init_subclass__ to be called here, which assigns tableName as the class name. This function should only do this in StructSettings classes and the like.
Also, I can't change the order of inheritance between StructSettings and DataclassModuleBase, it matters to me, so I can't use DataclassModuleBase to override __init_subclass__.
If my question above cannot be solved, then maybe I can redefine __init_subclass__ in the DataclassModuleBase without changing the inheritance order?
The only solution I have found is to add a check to the __init_subclass__
def __init_subclass__(cls, as_table = None, **kwargs) -> None:
    if 'Struct' not in cls.__name__:
        return
    cls.TableName = cls.__name__.replace('Struct', '', 1)

but I don't really like this solution, despite the fact that I am sure that all the classes I need will have "Struct" in the name.

This sounds like you need to seriously rethink your class hierarchy.

Why do you want to do that? What are you really trying to achieve?

@ndc85430
check my update in the question please

Dataclasses are not meant for inheritance - they don't behave well.
